# Update dynamically custom content on WooCommerce update checkout event

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

```php
class CheckoutTax
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // add a note after the order details, when a tax is charged and country changes 
        
        // the html snippet is shown after the order details on a page refresh
        add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', array($this, 'checkout_note_tax'));

        // the action is called when the country changes
        // but it does not show the html snippet at the correct place
        add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', array($this, 'checkout_note_tax'));

        // how to combine
        // - show HTML snippet after the order details
        // - act on a country change
    }

    /**
     * Show checkout note, tax paid
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function checkout_note_tax() {
        
        if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

        if (!is_checkout()) return;

        global $WOOCS;

        $total_tax = WC()->cart->get_totals()['total_tax'];
        $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

        error_log( $total_tax );
        error_log( $shipping_country );

        if( $total_tax > 0 && $shipping_country != 'CH') {
            ?>
            <h3>VAT / Custom Duties</h3>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

The hook *woocommerce_review_order_before_payment* shows the html snippet at the correct page, but only on a page refresh.

The hook *woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees* triggers changes made to the country field.

How can I combine an action to show a HTML snippet after the order details on the checkout page and update the HTML snippet when the shipping country is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something a bit different to get your custom content refreshed on `checkout_update` Ajax event. I have replaced `woocommerce_review_order_before_payment` hook with a more convenient one.

Now your content is also added to Ajax "order review fragments", so on "Update checkout" event your display gets refreshed dynamically.

Try the following *(commented)*:

```
class CheckoutTax
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', array( $this, 'checkout_display_custom_taxes'), 15 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', array( $this, 'update_checkout_custom_fragments') );
    }

    /**
     * Here your HTML content
     *
     * @return string
     */   
    public function output() {
        $total_tax = WC()->cart->get_totals()['total_tax'];
        $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    
        $html = '<div class="woocommerce-checkout-custom-tax">'; // Mandatory wrapper html
    
        if( $total_tax > 0 && $shipping_country !== 'CH') {
            $html .= sprintf('<h3>%s</h3>', __('VAT / Custom Duties', 'woocommerce') );
        }
        return $html . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Output html content in checkout page
     *
     * @return void
     */   
    public function checkout_display_custom_taxes() {
        echo $this->output();
    }

    /**
     * Add the html content to be refreshed on checkout update Ajax event
     *
     * @return array
     */   
    public function update_checkout_custom_fragments( $fragments ){
        // We add the selector class of our wrapper div as array key
        $fragments['.woocommerce-checkout-custom-tax'] = $this->output();
    
        return $fragments;
    }
}
```

For testing purpose in the child theme's functions.php file, I use additionally:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', function(){
    $CheckoutTax = new CheckoutTax();
});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

**Related:**

- [Move shipping options outside WooCommerce checkout order review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663964/move-shipping-options-outside-woocommerce-checkout-order-review/66664845#66664845)
- [Is there a way to add custom code into a public static function? (woocommerce update_order_review)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946335/is-there-a-way-to-add-custom-code-into-a-public-static-function-woocommerce-up/68980810#68980810)

Comment: Thanks for showing a "fragments" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, although it will show in the order table before the total. (I used something similar to add checkboxes for shipping insurance and calculating the insurance fee).

```
class CheckoutTax
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total',  array($this, 'checkout_note_tax'));
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total',  array($this, 'checkout_note_tax'));
    }
 
    /**
     * Show checkout note, tax/customs paid
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function checkout_note_tax() {
        
        if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

        global $WOOCS;

        $total_tax = WC()->cart->get_totals()['total_tax'];
        $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

        if( $total_tax > 0 && $shipping_country != 'CH') {
            ?>
                <tr class="woocommerce-shipping-insurance shipping">
                    <th><?php _e('VAT / Custom Duties', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr('checkout_note_tax'); ?>">
                        <p>VAT and custom duties ...
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }

}
```